# Factory class in Python with a mapping dictionary returns TypeError

Tags: python, factory

I made something like this dummy class:

```
class CreateCaseFactory:
    @classmethod
    def create(cls, user_id: uuid.UUID, type_: str) -> str:
        creator = cls.CASE_TO_METHOD_MAP.get(type_)
        if creator:
            return creator(user_id)
        else:
            raise Exception("Invalid type")

    @classmethod
    def _create_case_1(cls, user_id: uuid.UUID) -> str:
        result = f"Dummy Use Case 1 created for user {user_id}"
        return result

    @classmethod
    def _create_case_2(cls, user_id: uuid.UUID) -> str:
        result = f"Dummy Use Case 2 created for user {user_id}"
        return result

    CASE_TO_METHOD_MAP = {
        "case_1": _create_case_1,
        "case_2": _create_case_2,
    }
```

but I get an error when I try to run it:

```
        if creator:
>           return creator(user_id)
E           TypeError: 'classmethod' object is not callable
```

How can I make this factory class work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As the error message says, instances of `classmethod` are not callable. When you call a class method with something like `CreateCaseFactory.create(...)`, the descriptor protocol "extracts" the underlying function from the class method and calls it with `CreateCaseFactory` as the first argument.

`create_case_1` and `_create_case_2` should not be class methods, but regular functions.

```
class CreateCaseFactory:
    @classmethod
    def create(cls, user_id: uuid.UUID, type_: str) -> str:
        creator = cls.CASE_TO_METHOD_MAP.get(type_)
        if creator:
            return creator(cls, user_id)
        else:
            raise Exception("Invalid type")

    def _create_case_1(cls, user_id: uuid.UUID) -> str:
        result = f"Dummy Use Case 1 created for user {user_id}"
        return result

    def _create_case_2(cls, user_id: uuid.UUID) -> str:
        result = f"Dummy Use Case 2 created for user {user_id}"
        return result

    CASE_TO_METHOD_MAP = {
        "case_1": _create_case_1,
        "case_2": _create_case_2,
    }
```

Comment: Yeah that works but I get a warning form linter, which makes me think it is not how it is meant to be done in Python.

Comment: The issue is that the linter thinks you intend to use `_create_case_1` as an instance method, but you are really just using it as a private function to implement the actual class method. You *could* define it as a class method, then store the *name* of the method in the map and call it with `getattr(cls, creator)(user_id)`.

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to call the creator object, which is a class method. In Python, class methods are not directly callable as regular functions.
Example

```py
import uuid


class CreateCaseFactory:

    @classmethod
    def create(cls, user_id: uuid.UUID, type_: str) -> str:
        creator = cls.CASE_TO_METHOD_MAP.get(type_)
        if creator:
            return creator(cls, user_id)  # Call the class method using the class itself
        else:
            raise Exception("Invalid type")

    def _create_case_1(cls, user_id: uuid.UUID) -> str:
        result = f"Dummy Use Case 1 created for user {user_id}"
        return result

    def _create_case_2(cls, user_id: uuid.UUID) -> str:
        result = f"Dummy Use Case 2 created for user {user_id}"
        return result

    CASE_TO_METHOD_MAP = {
        "case_1": _create_case_1,
        "case_2": _create_case_2,
    }


uuid1 = uuid.UUID("12345678-1234-5678-1234-567812345678")
factory = CreateCaseFactory()
case_1 = factory.create(user_id=uuid1, type_="case_1")
print(case_1)
# Dummy Use Case 1 created for user 12345678-1234-5678-1234-567812345678
```

Comment: Simply adding `cls` as the first argument doesn't actually work (at least not with python 3.10) . If you really want to keep the `classmethod`, you need to access the function inside the `'classmethod' object` by calling its `__func__` method : `return creator.__func__(cls, user_id)`. However, the fact that you are explicitely calling a dunder method should be a hint that this is not "best practice".

Comment: you are right, example fixed